# Sorting part of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have a ruby array, and I want to sort all elements starting with index `i` till index `j`, in place. The rest of the array should not be modified. How can I implement this?

Comment: Well-worded question. @CodeGnome, admit it: you've been proved wrong. :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `a[i, j] = a[i, j].sort!` to sort from index `i` to index `j`. Example:

```
a = [8, 7, 5, 4, 3]
a[2..4] = a[2..4].sort!
a # => [8, 7, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I was going to comment it won't do what OP wants, but the change is good

Comment: Very nice, it seems you're on a roll today.

Comment: `a[2..4] = a[2..4].sort!` would be marginally more efficient, as it creates only one temporary array.

Comment: The example is correct, showing how to slice the array using a range, `2..4`. The first line is not correct, as `a[i, j] = a[i, j].sort` does not sort from index `i` to index `j`, but sorts from index `i` and then a length of `j`.